# What is the difference between itemismovable and drag&drop in QT

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

I have some rect on a QGraphicsView. I need to drag and drop one to a specific position. Is there a difference between set a item movable or drag and drop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Drag and Drop](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html) has nothing to do with whether or not an item is movable.

> Drag and drop provides a simple visual mechanism which users can use to transfer information between and within applications. (In the literature this is referred to as a "direct manipulation model".) Drag and drop is similar in function to the clipboard's cut and paste mechanism.

This is like when you drag an icon from your desktop to your application. Individual `QGraphicsItem`s can accept drag/drop events and you may handle them as you wish by implementing `dragEnterEvent`, `dragMoveEvent`, and `dragLeaveEvent`.

The term Drag & Drop in Qt is always used to refer to this, and should not be confused with the user's ability to move an object around on the screen with the mouse.

Comment: +1 You are right, I got misleaded by `By clicking on the item and then dragging, the item will move together with the mouse cursor.` which is really just mouse dragging and not Drag & Drop. (If you wonder, I posted a wrong answer which I now deleted)